# reference a class .net C#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I have a a class called CUser. I'm tyring to call a function in this class in another aspx page I have. This is how Im calling it:

```
CUser Logic = new CUser();
DataList1.DataSource = Logic.GetAllDate();
DataList1.DataBind();
```

Im getting the following error The type or name space name 'CUser' couldnt be found. My CUser class is in appcode in a folder named BLL. Am i missing something?

Thanks,

Comment: Have you included the assembly as a reference?

Comment: No shouldnt it recongize the class as it is in the app_code folder?

Comment: If you have no namespace around your `CUser` class, it should be visible immediately to your ASPX page. Otherwise use the `using` directive.

Answer (score 2):

If your class is in a folder it is likely that it is in another **Namespace**.
You have to include it into your file where your are using your `CUser` class.

As an example: `using MyApp.BLL;`

[Using Namespaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/dfb3cx8s%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Does it have the NameSpace?

If it has the namespace, you have to type like:

```
YourNameSpace.CUser Logic = new YourNameSpace.CUser();
```

Or, put using statement at the top like:

```
using YourNameSpace;
```

And, have you built your website?  Sometimes, you need to recompile/build the website to reflect the latest changes.